# How to refilter others dc.js charts when brush is off after being on?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

**[Please, follow the image during reading the instructions.]**
[image]
I have a line chart (1.b) which is used to zoom in a bar chart (1.a) and to select items in a scatter plot (2).

Once I brush the line chart (1.b), the others graphs (1.a and 2) apply the filter perfectly. When I turn off the brush the bar chart zoom out, given me the whole scope of the data back, **but** the scatter plot (2) does **not** make the dots appear again.

Please, see last scenario from top to bottom. Scatter plot keeps the previous filter.

what could I do to reset it in case the brush is off in line chart (1.b)?

Comment: How are you turning the brush off? There is some screwiness around dc.js brushes in my experience. Sometimes when they are turned on and off, they don't properly reset filters. If you share an example where we can recreate the problem, it will be easier to tell you exactly why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: just clicking on the side of it (interactively).

Comment: Well that should work :-) Do you have a filter handler defined on the chart or something? Can you share the full code for the charts?

Comment: Hello Ethan, thanks for your support. I could not reproduce it in fiddle in a simpler scenario, so the issue might be in another place in my messy code.

Comment: I could not reproduce it in fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/jth32/22/ because fiddle is not accepting scatterPlot as a function and I have no Idea why. Uncomment it for testing.

Comment: Anyhow, some just came to my mind and I could not find an answer for that. Is there a way to get all brushed and non-brushed items separately? When I say that, I am thinking on brushing the time-oriented line chart. http://fiddle.jshell.net/jth32/26/

Comment: Looks like you've included dc.js version 1.6 in your external dependencies. That is very old. Probably doesn't include scatterplot. Can you update?  On the 2nd question, you should open a new question for that one.

Comment: I update it to 1.7.5, which is the last version according to https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/ and it still did not work =/.

Comment: 1.7.5 is on the stable API, which does not have a scatterplot. You need one of the 2.0.0 betas.

Comment: Hello Ethan, I just figure out that I was using a group instead of a dimension in the .dimension() field of the barchart. When I was brushing/filtering it was not interacting with the others dimensions because it was a group and not a dimension. My bad. Thanks for the support anyhow =).

Comment: Didn't see this, earlier. Glad you got to the bottom of it!